# Why not use _.bind instead of _.bindAll?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

In this backbone example:

http://arturadib.com/hello-backbonejs/docs/1.html

```
(function($){
  var ListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('body'), // attaches `this.el` to an existing element.
    initialize: function(){
      _.bindAll(this, 'render'); // fixes loss of context for 'this' within methods
      this.render(); // not all views are self-rendering. This one is.
    },
    render: function(){
      $(this.el).append("<ul> <li>hello world</li> </ul>");
    }
  });
  var listView = new ListView();
})(jQuery);
```

Because only one argument ( function ) is passed, I don't see the point in using bindAll().

Here is the [underscore API](http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html)

Comment: `_.bindAll` used to be more common in Backbone because you needed it more, now `events` and `listenTo` use the expected `this` and everything else lets you specify the `this` (AKA `context`) when binding event handlers. `_.bindAll(this, ...)` in `initialize` is a bit of an anachronism now. You'll also note that your example uses `$(this.el)` instead of `this.$el` so your example is old, you should find more recent things to look at.

Answer (score 1):

`_.bindAll` replaces the methods in the object with the new methods, with context set to the object. `_.bind` returns a new function.

This is equivalent to:

`this.render = _.bind(this.render, this)`

Which is a bit more verbos, but is done anyway within [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html#section-67):

```
_.bindAll = function(obj) {
    var funcs = slice.call(arguments, 1);
    if (funcs.length === 0) throw new Error('bindAll must be passed function names');
    each(funcs, function(f) { obj[f] = _.bind(obj[f], obj); }); //in this line
    return obj;
  };
```